# PropertyGrid in PowerShell doesn't display all properties

Tags: powershell, propertygrid

I'm delving into making GUI's with PowerShell using Windows Forms, and I've been messing with the very useful and snappy-looking PropertyGrid object, but I'm not sure it likes to play very nice with PowerShell.  I'm especially having some issues with the Active Directory cmdlets.

I'd like to show an AD user object in a PropertyGrid.  For testing purposes, I created this simple function:

```
Function Show-Object
{
    $Form = New-Object "System.Windows.Forms.Form"
    $Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size @(600,600)
    $PropertyGrid = New-Object "System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGrid"
    $PropertyGrid.Dock = [System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle]::Fill
    $Form.Text = "$args"
    $PropertyGrid.SelectedObject = $args[0]
    $Form.Controls.Add($PropertyGrid)
    $Form.TopMost = $true
    $Form.ShowDialog()
}
```

I then run

```
PS> Show-Object (Get-ADUser Testing)
```

It displays exactly what I'd expect it to display.  On the other hand, when I run this

```
PS> Show-Object (Get-ADUser Testing -Properties *)
```

the PropertyCount in the result PropertyGrid goes up to the number I'd expect, but the additional properties still don't appear.  I don't actually want to display all properties as in this example, but adding specific properties doesn't seem to work either.  Is there a way to make this work the way I'd like to, or do I need to look for an alternate solution?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're planning with `Show-Object` but a [Lonely Administrator](http://jdhitsolutions.com/blog/) made a pretty nice function that does the same thing that your `Show-Object` does. It's called [Out-GridList](http://jdhitsolutions.com/blog/2013/05/friday-fun-view-objects-in-a-powershell-gridlist/). Maybe if you see how that script works you'll be able to fix your script. So for example I just copied the `Out-GridList` function to a test script and called the function in that same script.

```
function Out-GridList {
...
}
Get-ADUser Testing -Properties * | Out-GridList
```

[image: Output from Out-GridList]